# bash autocompletion with alias command

Tags: bash, autocomplete, alias

in my `~/.bashrc`, for git I have this alias

```
alias g='git'
```

how I can use the autocompletion of `git` with my alias `g` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following line to your `.bashrc` file:

```
complete -F XXX g
```

where `XXX` should be replaced by the value following `-F` in the output of the following command:

```
complete -p git
```

(It is likely, but not guaranteed, that this will be `_git`.)

Comment: thanks, I add this line `complete -o bashdefault -o default -o nospace -F _git g`

Comment: Actually only complete -F _git g would be needed. Not sure if et matters though.